# Use Google Maps Bubble as a Custom Tooltip Background

Tags: image, google-maps, tooltip

I want to use the Google Maps "bubble" in my web site.  It pops up when you click on a pin...

[image: Google Maps Bubble]
<sub>(source: [deltasys.com](http://www.deltasys.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2007/12/dealer_locator_example.jpg))</sub>

Has anybody done this?  I can't even find the required image(s) using Firebug.  If I can just find the image(s) that powers this bubble, I can handle the rest!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the images being used, presumably as sprites:

- [Popup](http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/sv_ALL/mapfiles/iw3.png)
- [Shadow](http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/sv_ALL/mapfiles/iws3.png)

Not sure you're at liberty to use them, tho

Comment: Looks like I can't accept my answer for a couple days, so forget it, I'm deleting it and accepting yours.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: heh, no worries. in response to your comment on your now deleted post, i used the 'net' tab in firebug, and filtered it to show images only. it was still quite an effort tho, the maps them self created quite a lot of noise in my filter =)

Comment: Now if only I can dig up the markup structure and accompanying CSS from Google to build the end result.  Ahhh, what am I saying, that's half the fun!

Comment: get it working on your own, and *then* check out how google did it =) the power of spriting techniques is quite appreciable when you consider that google use a 1144x370px image for a shadow effect that is rarely displayed in anything near that size.